# PowerBI DataSet is not refreshing

Tags: powerbi

I have a dataset that is published in a content pack then consumed by other users of the system. The data appears to be updated on the content pack:
[image: Webpack published view]

but the consumers don't seem to have the most recent data:
[image: Consumer's view]

How do I make it refresh / have it refresh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is being updated. The UI isn't reflecting the update but based on the visualizations the underlying data is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen something similar. My problem was that I had pinned an entire report onto the dashboard and that does not refresh in real time.

The solution was to create a tile containing the content I wanted and then pin that single tile onto the dashboard. That then updates correctly in real time.

Answer (score -1):

This is likely by design in how the UI updates work.   Here is article from the Microsoft PowerBI forums:

https://ideas.powerbi.com/knowledgebase/articles/732231-what-if-my-data-isn-t-up-to-date

Thanks,
Nathan